# Getting TS error with Redux dispatch action, `Property does not exist on type`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the following redux-thunk action:

```
import { Action } from "redux";
import { ThunkAction as ReduxThunkAction } from "redux-thunk";
import { IState } from "./store";

type TThunkAction = ReduxThunkAction<void, IState, unknown, Action<string>>;

export type TReturnValue = { someString: string };
export const someAction = (): TThunkAction => (dispatch): TReturnValue => ({
  someString: "some value"
});
```

And I dispatch the action like this:

```
const { someString } = dispatch(someAction());
```

which throws the error,

```
const { someString } = dispatch(someAction());
        ^^^^^^^^^^
Property 'someString' does not exist on type 'TThunkAction<void, IState, unknown, Action<string>>'
```

I've tried casting the result like this,

```
const { someString } = dispatch<TReturnValue>(someAction());
```

And I've tried redefining `TThunkAction`, but nothing worked.

How can I get Typescript to know what type to expect from the dispatch action?

[image: gracious-yalow-essnz?]

Comment: This is (in spite of my previous comments) a genuine bug which is being fixed by this commit: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/commit/d28ab03fd1d2dd1de402928a9589857e97142e09

Comment: I'm still a little confused. As far as I can tell, it hasn't been merged yet, and once it is, how would I apply it to my problem?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think dispatch() returns anything.
Dispatch is just to send the action to the reducers where you would read the payload of the actions.

If you need a value from your thunk you should fire a new action inside the thunk and handle that it in the reducer.

To read the value in your react component you should also be using useSelector to read specific values from your state.

Would be easier to explain if I knew what you where trying to do with the value.

Take a look at [redux with typescript](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript).
Or consider [Redux toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) for less boilerplate code with Typescript.

Comment: To answer your question, I'm trying to dispatch an action and return something, such as a string. There's no way to extend or create a type the way I'm trying to?

Comment: I think you might be using dispatch the wrong way in that case.
I would either:
A: Dispatch action, change state based on the action, use selector to get the value.
B: Just use a function, or a hook. 

It all depends on what you are trying to do. Are you doing something async? Or is it just taking some input and transforming it into some new output. Is the value just for a single component, or is it shared between components?

Comment: Technically `dispatch` returns the action that was dispatched.  That's why you see type `TThunkAction<void, IState, unknown, Action<string>>` which is the type of the action. @Mellet is totally right on this -- if you are trying to return a value from `dispatch` then you are designing this wrong.  You either A) store the value in the `state` and select it from the state or B) instead of doing your `fetch` (or whatever) from a thunk, do it from a pure function that you call from your component.  Handle the response in the component and then dispatch whatever action.

Comment: @MikeK a thunk is a function which receives `dispatch` as a prop, which allows it to do something and then dispatch an action.  Obviously what you've posted here is just a dummy so I don't know what your actual code looks like but I don't see any mention of you calling `dispatch` inside of `someAction` so I have to wonder if you're confused about the whole thing. https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk

Comment: ...aaannnddd after typing all that I've had an *"oh my god I'm actually wrong"* moment!  So it turns out that redux-thunk modifies the behavior of `dispatch` such that when calling a thunk it will return the thunk returned value rather than the thunk itself.  The current package typings don't support this but it was updated TODAY to fix the TS https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/commit/d28ab03fd1d2dd1de402928a9589857e97142e09 https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk/blob/b04e04ca9e4f9671ab5bd7f579a5de9f3ebf3c32/src/index.d.ts#L13

Comment: Thanks @LindaPaiste! I also had assumed this was part of the native redux behavior and couldn't figure out how they had managed to mess the typing up so bad. Good to know it's been fixed - will track that commit.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the fix that @Linda Paiste linked to in the comments manually, I added it and got the correct solution.

In actions.ts, I fixed the ReduxThunkAction to have the correct value and added the Dispatch type from the patch.

```
type ThunkAction<ReturnType> = ReduxThunkAction<
  ReturnType,
  IState,
  unknown,
  Action<string>
>;

export type TReturnValue = { someString: string };
export type TAnotherReturnValue = { anotherString: string };

export const someAction = (): ThunkAction<TReturnValue> => (dispatch) => ({
  someString: "some value"
});
export const anotherAction = (): ThunkAction<TAnotherReturnValue> => (
  dispatch
) => ({
  anotherString: "another value"
});

export interface Dispatch<A extends Action = AnyAction> {
  <TReturnType = any, TState = any, TExtraThunkArg = any>(
    thunkAction: ReduxThunkAction<TReturnType, TState, TExtraThunkArg, A>
  ): TReturnType;
}
```

In app.tsx, I just force the dispatch type to be the new manually added thunk type.

```
  const dispatch: Dispatch = useDispatch();
```

See code sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-field-vujrq?file=/src/App.tsx

**EDIT**: Answered the comment by making the ThunkAction helper as generic. The main point about this is to remember that the helper is just a helper and you could also just type each action separately as a `ReduxThunkAction`, the helper just saves some keystrokes and ensures consistency.

Comment: This only works for `TReturnValue`. If I have multiple actions, then I can't use this approach: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-dream-06obm?file=/src/actions.ts